# Subversion Merging Woes

Tags: svn, merge

I have a svn repository that I messed up a merge on - unfortunately, I didn't realize this right away and additional changes have been made to the repository since then. Here is a abstract snapshot of the situation

```
r100 - Created Branch
r101 - Changes to Trunk
r102 - Changes to Trunk
r103 - Change to branch
r104 - Change to branch
r105 - Re-Integrate Branch (Forgot to merge trunk changes into branch here)
r106 - Change to trunk
r107 - Revert trunk to r102
r108 - Merge trunk changes into Branch
r109 - Re-Integrate Branch
```

How do I re-apply the changes from <strike>r108</strike> r106 back into the trunk?

EDIT: To clarify, I have reintegrated the branch back in to the trunk, however i need to reapply the changes that were made to the trunk after the first broken merge.

Comment: For me question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't this work?

```
$ svn merge -c106  ^/trunk
```

This should add revision #106 back into trunk. You might need to do an `--ignore-ancestry` if you didn't revert using the `svn merge` syntax, but just simply overwrote the files when you reverted.